# Calculating modular roots over Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, gaussian-integers, computational-number-theory

Let $a+bi$ be a Gaussian integer.

Given another Gaussian integer $c+di$ how does one find $x^2\equiv(c+di)\bmod(a+bi)$?

Can you illustrate with $x^2\equiv 48\bmod(156\pm89i)$?

Comment: Do you have a way of doing this task for modular quadratic congruences in $\mathbf Z$? That would be a simpler case, so it'd be helpful to see what you have in mind there first.

Comment: There easy.. there are standard techniques in wiki.

Comment: https://www.rieselprime.de/ziki/Modular_square_root

Comment: Your example has a prime modulus in $\mathbf Z[i]$, with prime norm $p = 32257$, so the natural map $\mathbf Z/(p) \to \mathbf Z[i]/(156\pm 89i)$ is a ring isomorphism for both choices of sign. Thus your example is the same as solving $x^2 \equiv 48 \bmod p$ and you are satisfied by the methods for solving quadratic congruences in $\mathbf Z$. By the way, $48 = 4^2 \cdot 3$, so you might as well focus in the example on deciding if $3$ is a square rather than $48$,

Comment: @KCd I understand solving upto $x^2\equiv 48\bmod p$. Is it just $x\bmod(156\pm89i)$ after that? So you get $4$ roots?

Comment: There are two roots in $\mathbf Z[i]/(156 + 89i)$ and two roots in $\mathbf Z[i]/(156 - 89i)$, just as there are two roots of $x^2 - 48$ in $\mathbf Z/(11)$ and in $\mathbf Z/(13)$.  The roots of $x^2 - 48$ in $\mathbf Z/(32257)$ are $11342$ and $20915$ and both of these will also be roots of $x^2 - 48$ in $\mathbf Z[i]/(156 + 89i)$ and in $\mathbf Z[i]/(156 - 89i)$ (those are isomorphic rings, with a unique isomorphism between them).